# Why is $\displaystyle \sum_{d\le x}\log^2\left(\dfrac xd\right) = O(x)$?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

So the question is in the title itself. My approach is as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{d\le x}\log^2\left(\dfrac xd\right)&=\sum_{d\le x}(\log x-\log d)^2\\
&=\sum_{d\le x}(\log^2x-2\log x\log d+\log^2d)\\
&=x\log^2x-2\log x\log(\lfloor x\rfloor!)+\sum_{d\le x}\log^2d\\
&\approx x\log^2x-2\log x\log\left(x^{x+\frac12}e^{-x}\sqrt{2\pi}\right)+\sum_{d\le x}\log^2d\\
&=x\log^2x-2\left(x+\frac12\right)\log^2 x+2x\log x-2\log x\log(\sqrt{2\pi})+\sum_{d\le x}\log^2d\\
&=-x\log^2x-\log^2x+2x\log x-2\log x\log(\sqrt{2\pi})+\sum_{d\le x}\log^2d
\end{align}
where I used Stirling's appoximation in step $4$, and replaced $\lfloor x\rfloor$, assuming it reasonable. I couldn't proceed further.

Comment: To avoid confusion: Do you mean by $O(f)=O(g)$ that $f=O(g)$ as well as  $g=O(f)$ must hold?

Comment: @vitamind, I just mean $f=O(g)$ by that notation (since $O(f)$ is meant to be a function which is bounded by a constant multiple of $f$, if $f$ is bounded by a constant multiple of $g$, then this function is also bounded by a constant multiple of $g$). I've edited the question to make it clearer, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/M_Mathematics/MT_Number%20theory/Nathanson%20M.B.%20Elementary%20Methods%20in%20Number%20Theory%20(GTM,%20Springer,2000)(ISBN%200387989129)(518s)_MT_.pdf

Comment: Theorems 6.11 and 6.12.

Comment: @Martund Ah yes, I see you removed the $O$ in the title. Everything's clear now.

Comment: I don't see where you got the 3rd step actually...

Comment: @Mike, I distributed the sum over the three terms. First one was constant term, second one gets into this form because $\log1+\log2+\dots+\log\lfloor x\rfloor = \log(\lfloor x\rfloor!)$, and the last term I kept intact.

Comment: I see it now....

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Stirling, only that
$$\sum_{d\le x} \log^2 (x/d)=
 \sum_{d\le x} \int_d^{d+1} (\log x-\log d)^2 dt
=\sum_{d\le x} \int_d^{d+1} (\log x- \log t+O(1/t))^2 dt $$
$$ = \int_1^{x+1} (\log x- \log t)^2 dt+O(\int_1^{x+1} \frac{\log x}{t} dt)$$

$$ = 2 x-2 - 2 \log x - \log^2 x+O(\log^2 x) $$

Comment: How are you going from the second to the third step? Won't replacing $\log d$ by $\log t$ make an error of at most $1$ instead of $O(\frac1t)$?

Comment: $(\log u)' = 1/u=O(1/t)$  on $[d,t]$ an interval of length $\le 1$

Comment: Still couldn't make sense. Wha is the job of derivative here?

Comment: $f(b)=f(a)+O(|b-a|\sup_{u\in [b,a]} |f'(u)|)$

Comment: Hmmm, Ok got it now.

Answer (score 0):

You’re adding up log^2(x/d). For how many d are is log^2(x/d) <= 4? (Whenever x/e <= d <=x). For how many d are you adding a value between 4 and 9, between 9 and 16, between 16 and 25 etc? That gives you a nice upper bound for the sum.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How do I find the number of $d$'s between $x$ and $\frac xe$?